# Is there an excel function that I can use to give values based on what the time value is?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm looking for a function I can use that returns "Night Off Prime" if the time a programme was on was between 11pm - 5:59am, "Day Off Prime" if it was on between 6am - 5:59pm and "Prime" if it was on between 6pm - 10:59pm.

I've tried using the IFS function with the code being     =IFS(OR(G3>=23,G3<6),"Night Off Prime", OR(G3>=6,G3<18),"Day Off Prime", OR(G3>=18,G3,23),"Prime")

The G column is just the hh format of the hour it was on, with the values formatted as Number.

I've also tried       =IFS(OR(BK3>=23:00,BK3<06:00),"Night Off Prime", OR(BK3>=06:00,G3<18:00),"Day Off Prime", OR(BK3>=18:00,BK3,23:00),"Prime")

Here the BK column is the time the programme was on in the hh:mm time format

The main trouble I'm finding there is how to label time between two different times such as between 11pm - 5:59am instead of just past 11pm. I used the OR logical but that doesn't seem to have worked.

I've also tried a VLOOKUP function     =VLOOKUP(BK2,$AC$899:$AD$901,2, TRUE)

Here the table array is

AC899 Night Off Prime AD899 23:00-05:59

AC900 Day Off Prime AD900 06:00-17:59

AC901 Prime AD901 18:00-22:59

Comment: XLOOKUP supports a not exact match type (next best smaller or next best bigger). So you could use a reference table with either the lower limit or the upper limit only. You may also want to split the range form 11pm to 5:59am into 2 ranges with the same naming (before and after midnight).

Comment: Antonio, did my answer solve your question? If so, would be great you confirm&upvote otherwise otherwise feel free to post what is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the IFS you may want to adjust like this (should work in the similar way for hh:mm as well):

```
=IFS(G3<6;"Night Off Prime";G3<18;"Day Off Prime";G3<23;"Prime";TRUE;"Night Off Prime")
```

(may replace `;` with `,` depending on regional setting)

alternatively:

```
=IFS(G3<0;"#N/A";G3<6;"Night Off Prime";G3<18;"Day Off Prime";G3<23;"Prime";G3<24;"Night Off Prime";TRUE;"#N/A")
```

Comment: I tried the top one and got an error message saying that there's a problem with this formula (I did change the ; to ,) and for the bottom one, it just said #N/A

Comment: Can you post your formula for checking？(maybe still somewhere a “;”?) I copied directly from the cell, working. I hope you understand the logic there: basically just need the upper limit without any OR. The second is the same just adding #N/A if the number is negative or >24

Answer (score 0):

"The main trouble I'm finding there is how to label time between two different times such as between 11pm - 5:59am instead of just past 11pm."
Add a column H2 `= G2 + 1/24`
Then your ranges are 0 to 7/24, 7/24 to 19/24 and 19/24 to 24/24, so you don't have an interval split over a resetting of the clock to zero.